# Server-side AJAX directory browser

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, treeview, directory-structure

Like many large organisations we have a giant shared network drive where a lot of important files are kept. To help people add links to these files there is a "x-drive link creator" with an file input tag. People select the file they want and submit the form. Once submitted the filename is taken and converted into an appropriate link.

Ignoring the issue of sending unnecessary traffic over the network this relies on the fact that older browsers sent the fully qualified filename. As a quick fix for newer browsers I've replaced the file input with a text box which people have to enter the file location in.

I want to improve this by having a Javascript tree selector so people can navigate to the folder they want. There are already several JS treeviews available although due to the huge nature of the shared drive it would be highly impractical to pre-fill it with all the files and their locations. The only way I can see of doing this is to have one that requests the files for an individual directory and each time a click is made sending the next level via AJAX. Rather than reinventing the wheel )and likely making a hash job of it) are there any existing treeviews with both a client and server side component that could handle this?

We are using ASP MVC 2 and JQuery as our main frameworks so anything using them would be preferred but I'd happily accept any other combination if it is a fully working solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) is a nice plugin which could be used and supports AJAX with JSON.

Comment: It seems OK though between posting this and getting your answer I found [JQuery File Tree](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) which for basic use cases I think is simpler and nicer but since you're the only one to respond you get the accept.